# Found this info in my Google doc app not sure how it got there

Tags: logging

I found this information in my Google documents app. I am not sure how it got there. I am wanting to know what it is and what is the meaning.

Log_1522393200000.txt

```
2018/03/29 21:13 screen w,h,d=480..792..1.5 
2018/03/29 21:13 GetAppRunNum 
2018/03/29 21:14 InCallBaseActivityOnResume 
2018/29/03 21:14 InCallBaseActivityDisplayResourse 
2018/03/29 21:15 OnDerstroy
```

Comment: How exactly did you find this information in the app? Was it in a document?

Comment: I think I know what it means but it was just in my document app out of nowhere